# Migrating tables from development to production

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.9

I have both production and development environment, need to move my Magento database from development to production, there is lot of data like customer details, vendor details, order details etc in production database, how to move development DB to this without losing live data, as there are changes in development DB

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to 
1.create backup of your live database, save is safe place.

2. In phpmyadmin of your development store, export only tables that you changed.
   3 import this tables to your life store